# Wait for mapped store getter to update child property

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have the following vuex getters

```
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash'

// if has token, we assume that user is logged in our system
export const isLogged = ({ token }) => !isEmpty(token)
// get current user data
export const currentUser = ({ user }) => user
export const timeLimit = ({ token_ttl }) => token_ttl
export const getToken = ({ token }) => token
```

I have the following computed Vuex properties in a child component

```
 name: "ProfilePic",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['currentUser']),
    url() {
      return new String('').concat(window.location.protocol, '//', window.location.hostname , ':8000', '/games/create/?search=player_id:').valueOf()
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.currentUser)
  },
  watch: {
    currentUser(value, old){
      console.re.log('ok', value, old);
      new QRCode(document.querySelector(".profile-userpic"), {
        text: this.url + value,
        width: 128,
        height: 128,
        colorDark : "#000000",
        colorLight : "#ffffff",
        correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
      })
    }
  }
```

the parent

```
 import ProfilePic from '../../components/general/qrcode.vue'

 export default {
    name: 'CcDashboard',
    methods : {
      ...mapActions(['checkUserToken', 'setMessage'])
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['isLogged'])
    },
    mounted() {
      this.checkUserToken().then(tkn => this.$store.dispatch('setMessage', {type: 'success', message: 'Your Game Starts Now!!!!'})).catch(err =>  this.$store.dispatch('setMessage', {type: 'error', message: ['Your time is up!']}))
    },
    components: {
      'profile-pic': ProfilePic
    }
  }
```

Store

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  modules,
  plugins,
  getters,
  strict: false, //process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
})
```

I'm using VuexPersist with localforage

```
localforage.config({
  name: 'vuevue'
});

const vuexLocalStorage = new VuexPersist({
  key: 'vuex', // The key to store the state on in the storage provider.
  storage: localforage, // or window.sessionStorage or localForage
  // Function that passes the state and returns the state with only the objects you want to store.
  // reducer: state => ({ Collect: state.Collect, Auth: state.Auth}),
  // Function that passes a mutation and lets you decide if it should update the state in localStorage.
  // filter: mutation => (true)
  modules: ['Auth','Collect'],
  asyncStorage: true
})
export const RESTORE_MUTATION = vuexLocalStorage.RESTORE_MUTATION
// // create a new object and preserv original keys
export default [...app.plugins, vuexLocalStorage.plugin]
```

executing `console.log` on `mounted()` I get

```
{__ob__: Observer}current_points: 45email: "qhegmann@jast.com"id: 2name: "Sandrine Cruickshank"total_points: 45__ob__: Observerdep: Dep {id: 20, subs: Array(4)}value: {id: 2, name: "Sandrine Cruickshank", email: "qhegmann@jast.com", current_points: 45, total_points: 45, …}
```

However,

When running the logic the `this.currentUser.id` returns **undefined** rather than a value( which it does)

Is it that I need to "wait" for it to properly populate from the store? or do I need to call it from the `$store.dispatch()` ?

Comment: No, you don't need to wait. Show the `state` and getters declaration of the store.

Comment: @acdcjunior not sure what you mean here....are you asking if the file is properly imported? the property exists in the "Vue" chrome ext and refreshing it a couple times does yield the result hence i believe it is not being set in time

Comment: Hum.. It is hard to understand with words only. Can you show the code (relevant parts) for the state and getters of your store?

Comment: @acdcjunior updated the question. Hope this helps

Comment: In your store code, you show the `store` and  `getters` variables, but you also need to show their declaration (and their importing, if applicable). For example, at the top you show the getters, but don't show them being "combined" into the `getters` object that is utimately used in the store.

Comment: @acdcjunior figured it out. it had to do with the vuex-persist package and updating to a new version

Comment: Humm.. good to know! I see! Besides linking, can you summarise it so others in the future can get around it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and had to do with a bug with one of my packages[enter link description here](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist/issues/15)

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want here is to watch the state of your computed property itemGetter, and when itemGetter is different from null/undefined trigger the method createProductSet ? https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

```
computed : {
    ...mapGetters([
        'itemGetter'
    ])
},

watch : {
    itemGetter(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (typeof newVal == null || typeof newVal == undefined)
            return

        this.createProductSet(newVal)           
    }
},

methods : {
    createProductSet(id){
        // logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I stepped away from my computer but I believe this is what I was also trying to accomplish. So mapped "getter" functions can be watched as well I assume? Will have to confirm I did this when I get home

Comment: Keep in mind that your getter is a computed property of your component, so you can watch it like you can watch another computed or data property. Anyway, as said acdcjunior, a more detailed explaination of your problem is welcomed, maybe this solution still not the good one :)